# jQuery POST to a PHP controller returns an error, but I still get data back

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

When I make the POST to a PHP page, the echo'ed data still comes back to me but the jQuery AJAX says it's not a success. Why would this be? And further, how can I actually "print" out the data once I get it back?

My PHP is below:

```
<?php 
$userEmail = $_POST['username'];
$userPassword = $_POST['password'];
//Login Function
$data = array("username" => $userEmail, $userPassword => "password");                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);                                                
$ch = curl_init('http://*****/****/**/Login');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1 );                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json')                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$obj = json_decode($result);
echo $obj;
echo '<br /><br />';
echo '<b>Each array and objects in table:</b> <br />';
echo '<hr>';
echo '<br />';
echo '<table border="1">';
echo '<tr><td>Medical Entity:</td><td>Date:</td><td>Type:</td><td>ID:</td></tr>';
foreach ($obj as $key => $value) {
    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $value->date . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $value->Name . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $value->dealType . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $value->id . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

The jQuery AJAX is below:

```
<div id="test">
Testing Stuff!
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#submit').click(function () {
var username = '***@****.com';
var password = 'password';
var data = '&username=' +  username + '&password=' + password;

        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "/****/data.php",  
            data: data,  
            dataType: "json",  
            success: function(e){   
                for(var i=0;i<e.length;i++){
                    document.write(e[i]);
                }
            },  
            error: function(e){   
                for(var i=0;i<e.length;i++){
                    $('#test').html(e[i]);
                } 
        });  

  //cancel the submit button default behaviours
        return false;
    }); 

});
</script>
```

My ultimate goal is to write out the data I get from the PHP page to a DIV on my HTML page via AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling your php function using `dataType: json`, meaning jQuery is expecting a JSON result to be returned. Your php file is returning HTML. Remove the dataType: JSON setting.

The variable that gets passed to the `success` function is not an array. You just need to do something like `$('#test').html(e);`

Comment: See 'error' at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings for details on what the error function parameters are.

Comment: You are correct sir! Its working better so far - I can see the data. However, it redirects me to the PHP page where it prints it out, rather than actually print it in the div.

Comment: Maybe your `return false;` isn't preventing the click event from bubbling up. Try changing your click event to `
$('#submit').click(function (event) {` and add as the first line `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: I added those suggestions, but its still redirecting. Should I get rid of the `return false`?

Comment: I added those suggestions, but its still redirecting. Should I get rid of the `return false`?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a lot of issues.

### Send JSON

I know that you are trying to send JSON, but you're doing it wrong. First you try to get JSON data using `json_decode($php_object)`, but you should be using `json_encode($php_object)`, since you have to encode a PHP object to the JSON notation (which is a string). Then you are appending HTML to this JSON, which doesn't make sense. You should do something like this:

```
$json_output = json_encode(
  array(
    "result" => $result,
    "html" => $some_html_you_generated_before
  )
)
```

Then in Javascript you can just access your data using `data.result` and `data.html`.

### Don't use curl

I don't know why you're using curl :). Just forget about it for now and use `header('Content-Type: application/json);` before you `echo` your JSON data.

Comment: Im using curl because the PHP page is actually getting data from another WCF service.

Comment: Okay. Still, my first suggestion still applies.